# OSX Widget works in browser, but not on dashboard

Tags: xml, macos, rss, widget

For school I'm working on a OSX Widget. It's a widget that retrieves data from an xml file and puts that in an ul depending on two selectors. While programming, I tested it in the browser and everything works fine, but when I convert it to a widget (.wdgt) everything works, but it doesn't retrieve the data from the xml file.

Am I using any methods that OSX Widgets don't support?

Here's the code I use for retrieving the data.

```
if(document.getElementById('leftbox').value == "ict" && document.getElementById('rightbox').value == "hbo") {
$.get("ict_hbo.xml", function (data) {
    $(data).find("item").each(function () { // or "item" or whatever suits your feed
        var el = $(this);

        $('<li><a href="' + el.find("link").text() + '" target="_blank">' + el.find("title").text() + '</a></li>').appendTo("ul");
    });
});
```

}